# PCA on Transposed Dataframe

Tags: r

I have a data set of 4 variables and 16 observations. I want to apply PCA over the first column. I have transposed my dataframe so that I can run prcomp. I am using prcomp so there is no limit for the number of variables being more than observations.

```
#Transpose the dataframe
n <- SkillCount_df$Skill
t_SkillCount_df <- as.data.frame(t(SkillCount_df[, -1]))
colnames(t_SkillCount_df) <- n
str(t_SkillCount_df)

summary(t_SkillCount_df)

#Apply PCA
pca_salary <- prcomp(t_SkillCount_df, scale. = T, center = T)
```

The code that I run doesn't have any errors but instead of getting 16 PCs I get 3 PCs.

the summary and structure of the data seem fine. All values are numerical and the 16 variables that I want to apply pca for, are the variable names.

Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you  provide a sample data using `dput(x)`

Comment: The number of PCs will be determined by the smaller of the two dimensions of your data.